# Bootstrap flex issue

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div className="row d-flex">
  <div>
    <h3>Duration</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Distance</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Back to Center</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

The d-flex is not working while other bootstrap classes works properly.i want it to be in horizental line these h3's

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Duration</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Distance</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Back to Center</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap you can do it like this 2 way

One way

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Duration</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Distance</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Back to Center</h3>
      </div>
</div>
```

Another way

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <div>
        <h3>Duration</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Distance</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Back to Center</h3>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rafi for your answers it works with your given code